# Как узнать сколько занимает кеш моего приложения?

Tags: android, kotlin, кэширование

Как можно узнать сколько занимает кеш моего приложения?
Например я использую Glide, который кеширует всякие изображения загружающиеся по сети, и нужно посмотреть, сколько он там "закешировал" в мегабайтах. Видел подобные реализации в разных приложениях, в настройках. Там была возможность посмотреть сколько занято приложением и кнопка: очистить кеш.
Пример приложение телеграм:
[image: телеграм]

Comment: то есть вам нужно реализовать функционал системного приложения настроек?

Comment: @Andrew, нет, просто узнать нужно, сколько в моём приложении весь кеш весит. Реализацию очистки я уже нагуглил, там одной командой кеш грохнуть можно.

Comment: По идее кэш - это просто папка в директории вашего приложения. Которая так и называется - `cache`. Получите её, получите её размер и по кнопке удаляйте всё её содержимое.